# gcloud.app.deploy Error Response: [13] default Cloud Build service account or user-specified service account does not have access to the bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, websocket, gcloud, ktor

I'm trying to deploy a [Ktor server to google cloud app engine](https://ktor.io/docs/google-app-engine.html#deploy-app), but when I run `./gradlew appengineDeploy`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Failed to create cloud build: invalid bucket "[xxxxxxxxxxxx].cloudbuild-logs.googleusercontent.com"; default Cloud Build service account or user-specified service account does not have access to the bucket
com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcClientException: <eye3 title='/ArgoAdminNoCloudAudit.CreateBuild, INVALID_ARGUMENT'/> APPLICATION_ERROR;google.devtools.cloudbuild.v1/ArgoAdminNoCloudAudit.CreateBuild;invalid bucket "[xxxxxxxxxxxx].cloudbuild-logs.googleusercontent.com"; default Cloud Build service account or user-specified service account does not have access to the bucket;AppErrorCode=3;StartTimeMs=1711387952607;unknown;ResFormat=uncompressed;ServerTimeSec=0.782722356;LogBytes=256;Non-FailFast;EndUserCredsRequested;EffSecLevel=none;ReqFormat=uncompressed;ReqID=49272bf8591f5427;GlobalID=0;Server=[2002:a05:6f20:2d92:b0:190:a0f7:31dc]:4001.
```

Not sure if any other info would be relevant to solving this?

I tried going to the Cloud Build Settings page, and then enabling the 'App Engine Admin' service, but that didn't do anything.
I also tried reauthenticating with `gcloud auth login`, and using a different account, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78221129/gcloud-app-deploy-error-response-13-failed-to-create-cloud-build-invalid-buc) and I was told that it's [a GCP outage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78227138/3579458). There is a suggested workaround that worked for me as well: enable the Compute Engine API for the project where app deploy is failing. I wonder if it helps you too.

Comment: Thanks for reposting and sharing the answer; it worked for me!